# Confused of declaring this kind of array

Tags: c++, arrays, std-pair

I was reading this [code](https://github.com/ftiasch/acm-icpc/commit/aaba05fb6a33cc04966077f6fe9855ee865a0144)

there is a line : `pair <int, int> approach[1 << 18][17]`

I don't know what is the meaning of this declaration : `approach[ 1<<18 ][17];`

Can anyone help?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In this context, `<<` is the bit left shift operator. `1 << 18` means take the binary representation of `1` and shift it to the left by 18. This is 2<sup>18</sup> (2 to the power 18, or `262144`). So you have a very large 2D array of pairs:

```
pair <int, int> approach[262144][17];
```

Answer (score 2):

`<<` is the bit left shift operator.

So `1 << 18` is an integer constant that has a value of 2<sup>18</sup>.

Answer (score 1):

It simply means 2^18, 2 to the power of 18.

The code is missing some explanations, the only real good informations is

```
// SGU 502 -- Digits Permutation
```

Ah its about digit permutation, so

```
pair <int, int> approach[1 << 18][17]
```

might be used to store the permutations, unless there is some limitation on the permutations the amount of permutations should be N! (hopefully [N!](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Factorial) <= (1<<18)).

But the definition doesn't tell anything about that, lets see if we can make it more clear (and hopefully right).

```
const int maxLength = 17;
const int maxPermutation = 1 << (maxLength+1);
pair <int, int> approach[maxPermutation ][maxLength]
static_assert(factorial(maxLength) <= maxPermutation, "approach might not be able to hold all permutations");
```